# silvertunnel-ng netlib 0.0.4 in android

Tags: android, tor, silvertunnel, netlib

I want to ask if it is possible to use silvertunnel-ng netlib 0.0.4 on an android device. I try it to use it but i have a problem with security calculation in Encryption class of the library.

Warning message is :

```
WARN org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption - verifySignature(): try to fix bug in security calculation with OpenJDK-6 java web start (ticket #59)
04-14 22:01:28.262  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] WARN org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption - verifySignature(): original decryptedDigest=01:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:a0:22:cd:61:ae:b0:44:f7:a2:a6:03:22:90:79:66:b6:51:c4:ec:de
04-14 22:01:28.262  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] WARN org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption - verifySignature(): dataDigest              =a0:22:cd:61:ae:b0:44:f7:a2:a6:03:22:90:79:66:b6:51:c4:ec:de
04-14 22:01:28.272  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] WARN org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption - verifySignature(): try to fix bug in security calculation with OpenJDK-6 java web start (ticket #59)
04-14 22:01:28.272  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] WARN org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption - verifySignature(): original decryptedDigest=01:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:3c:46:3d:7e:ac:1b:79:cb:d5:da:ba:1c:1a:0f:17:fa:13:f2:d0:07
04-14 22:01:28.272  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] WARN org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption - verifySignature(): dataDigest              =3c:46:3d:7e:ac:1b:79:cb:d5:da:ba:1c:1a:0f:17:fa:13:f2:d0:07
04-14 22:01:28.282  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] WARN org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption - verifySignature(): try to fix bug in security calculation with OpenJDK-6 java web start (ticket #59)
04-14 22:01:28.282  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] WARN org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption - verifySignature(): original decryptedDigest=01:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:03:73:9f:06:08:84:cc:9f:20:87:62:27:c6:84:e6:06:10:3e:80:63
04-14 22:01:28.282  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] WARN org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption - verifySignature(): dataDigest              =03:73:9f:06:08:84:cc:9f:20:87:62:27:c6:84:e6:06:10:3e:80:63
04-14 22:01:28.292  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] WARN org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption - verifySignature(): try to fix bug in security calculation with OpenJDK-6 java web start (ticket #59)
04-14 22:01:28.292  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] WARN org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption - verifySignature(): original decryptedDigest=01:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:ac:67:12:d3:81:4c:ea:7c:c9:20:a2:44:93:a4:55:16:bb:43:6b:64
04-14 22:01:28.292  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] WARN org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.util.Encryption - verifySignature(): dataDigest              =ac:67:12:d3:81:4c:ea:7c:c9:20:a2:44:93:a4:55:16:bb:43:6b:64
04-14 22:01:28.632  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] INFO org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryConsensus - validUntil=Tue Apr 14 22:00:00 EEST 2015 is too old for currentDate=Tue Apr 14 22:01:28 EEST 2015



04-14 22:01:37.632  [org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.directory.DirectoryManagerThread] INFO org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.tor.clientimpl.Tor - TorNetLayer new status: Router descriptors (Tor router details) will be loaded (30%)

[ControlNetSocketThread] INFO org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.control.ControlNetSocketThread - send timeout to ControlNetSocket(LoggingNetSocket(Socket2NetSocket(Socket[address=/82.94.251.203,port=80,localPort=37591]))): overall timeout reached
04-14 22:02:38.517   [ControlNetSocketThread] INFO org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.control.ControlNetSocketThread - send timeout to ControlNetSocket(LoggingNetSocket(Socket2NetSocket(Socket[address=/86.59.21.38,port=80,localPort=52887]))): overall timeout reached
04-14 22:03:08.799   [ControlNetSocketThread] INFO org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.control.ControlNetSocketThread - send timeout to ControlNetSocket(LoggingNetSocket(Socket2NetSocket(Socket[address=/128.31.0.39,port=9131,localPort=37239]))): overall timeout reached
04-14 22:03:39.192   [ControlNetSocketThread] INFO org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.control.ControlNetSocketThread - send timeout to ControlNetSocket(LoggingNetSocket(Socket2NetSocket(Socket[address=/171.25.193.9,port=443,localPort=46458]))): overall timeout reached
04-14 22:04:09.524   [ControlNetSocketThread] INFO org.silvertunnel_ng.netlib.layer.control.ControlNetSocketThread - send timeout to ControlNetSocket(LoggingNetSocket(Socket2NetSocket(Socket[address=/208.83.223.34,port=443,localPort=56812]))): overall timeout reached
```

Overall timeout reached and never connecting to the TOR network!

Answer (score 2):

This warning message has nothing to do with the real error.
This is just to show that the normal implementation of calculating the Signature is different on some JVMs, as this message is not providing any value I have removed the logging of this message from the library.

The real error can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276406/getsession-closes-socket).
This is now solved and the SilverTunnel-NG is now able to connect to the Tor-Network.

The only thing which is currently not working is the setup of a hiddenservice.

An Android-sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/B4dT0bi/hiddenservice-android).

The overall-timeout usually happens if the Router information cannot be loaded fast enough from the tor network.

On Android there are 2 main reasons why this could happen:

- Network speed
- Garbage Collector is stopping the threads because of to much memory usage

The SilverTunnel-NG currently uses around 100-200 MB RAM which is too much for normal Android Apps.

To overcome this issue check out the above mentioned Android-sample project.